# Weird interaction of delayed_job, daemons, koala, pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, delayed-job, koala

I've been debugging a weird rails problem that appears to only occur
when using all four of these gems:

- delayed_job
- daemons
- koala
- pg

Basically, if I try to make a facebook graph api call via koala
from a delayed job, my postgres server connection gets destroyed and
will not reconnect.

By introducing logging statements all over various gems (local copies),
i've managed to nail it down to happening INSIDE of a call to
Faraday.get  (koala uses Faraday for HTTP).
More specifically, it happens in build_response.

This ONLY happens if I start delayed job via the 'bin/delayed_job start'
method that results in a call to daemonize()

If I start the delayed_job worker via the rake task 'rake jobs:work',
the problem does not reproduce.

Below is example diagnostic output when running in daemon mode.  Sorry that
I do not have a stack trace because delayed_job does not provide one in its
error output:

```
%%% before Koala.make_request, about to query db
%%% sqlres is [{"count"=>"5"}]
%%% before Faraday.new, about to query db
%%% sqlres is [{"count"=>"5"}]
%%% after Faraday.new, about to query db
%%% sqlres is [{"count"=>"5"}]
%%% about to send get to #<Faraday::Connection:0x007fc8c9ab3580 @parallel_manager=nil,        @headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.0"}, @params={"access_token"=>REDACTED}, @options=#<Faraday::RequestOptions (empty)>, @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions verify=true>, @default_parallel_manager=nil, @builder=#<Faraday::RackBuilder:0x007fc8c9ab2fe0 @handlers=[Koala::HTTPService::MultipartRequest, Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp]>, @url_prefix=#<URI::HTTPS:0x007fc8c9ab2c20 URL:https://graph.facebook.com/>, @proxy=nil>
%%% before build_response, about to query db
%%% sqlres is [{"count"=>"5"}]
%%% after build_response, about to query db
2014-10-22T14:04:51-0500: [Worker(delayed_job host:steves-mbp.attlocal.net pid:19265)] Job FriendsRefresher (id=257) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() : Select count(*) from users
PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor:               SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM pg_class c
              LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
              WHERE c.relkind in ('v','r')
              AND c.relname = 'delayed_jobs'
              AND n.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
```

Does anybody have any ideas about why daemonize and Faraday would interact
in this way to screw up my postgres database connection?

Alternatively, do you have any suggestions about how to effectively use Delayed Job in a production environment deployed with Capistrano without using daemon mode?

Comment: Is something trying to keep the PostgreSQL socket open across process boundaries?

Comment: Do not know but the diagnostic output above shows that the sql connection is just fine through the first 5 queries sent to it.  It only blows up immediately after calling Faraday.get.  I am pretty sure that the Faraday.get call would not fork, return and resume from the return point but in a child process.

Comment: Can you fork off a `rake jobs:work` through Capistrano? I'm not sure what generates the offending query but it seems to be trying to see if the `delayed_jobs` table exists by asking the system tables.

Comment: Could be done.  Basically require rewriting the daemons gem as a bash script.  Stopping, restarting, and ensuring a single process instance are the nontrivial challenges.